# Pass objects in array into inquirer list choices

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, spotify

I have a simple node.js application to search the Spotify API for songs. Because there are songs with the same names by a different artist, I want the user to be able to select the track desired from a list using the inquirer package.

The methods below will add the data from the search results into an object, and push them into an array. I would then like to pass that array into the inquirer prompt, where the user can select an item.

When selected, I need to be able to get all of the data from the trackData object, for whichever selection the user made.

If there's a better way of doing this please let me know. Thanks s.o.

```
           let trackFetcher = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                for(let track of data.tracks.items)
                {
                    var trackData = {
                        name: track.name,
                        album: track.album.name,
                        artist: track.artists[0].name,
                        url: track.external_urls.spotify,
                    }

                    tracks.push(trackData);
                    resolve(tracks);
                }
            });

            trackFetcher.then((tracks) => {
                inquirer.prompt([
                    {
                      type: 'list',
                      message: 'Select a track from the list',
                      choices: tracks,
                      name: "track"
                  }]).then(function(selected) {
                     //Do stuff with the result
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array of objects should contain objects with 2 keys: name and value where name is the message to display and value the object that will be selected.

Fixed by changing my object to:

```
                    var trackData = {
                        name : track.name + " by: " + track.artists[0].name,
                        value : {
                            name: track.name,
                            album: track.album.name,
                            artist: track.artists[0].name,
                            url: track.external_urls.spotify,
                        }
                    }
```